# How can i access multiple servers databases in loop in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to access databases in loop which are in different different servers but i am getting error:

> "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_DATA_EXTRACTOR, Line 27 Incorrect syntax near '@DATABASE_NAME'."

```
IF OBJECT_ID('SP_DATA_EXTRACTOR') IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE SP_DATA_EXTRACTOR 
GO CREATE PROCEDURE [DBO].SP_DATA_EXTRACTOR AS 
DECLARE @UNIT_ID INT;
DECLARE @SERVER_NAME VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @DATABASE_NAME VARCHAR(100);
BEGIN
   DECLARE DATACURSOR CURSOR FOR 
   SELECT
      UNIT_ID,
      SERVER_NAME,
      DATABASE_NAME 
   FROM
      UNIT_MASTER 
   WHERE
      STATUS = 'A';
OPEN DATACURSOR;
FETCH NEXT 
   FROM
      DATACURSOR INTO @UNIT_ID,
      @SERVER_NAME,
      @DATABASE_NAME;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
   DELETE
      VW_REFUNDS_TABLE 
   WHERE
      UNIT_ID = @UNIT_ID 
      AND CONVERT(DATE, DATECREATED, 103) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE(), 103);
INSERT INTO
   VW_REFUNDS_TABLE(UNIT_ID, TICKETTOTAL, DATECREATED, REFUNDDATE, DEBITAMOUNT, CREDITAMOUNT, TERMINALID, CASHIER, TERMINAL, REFUNDMINS, MANAGER, USERID, ID) 
   SELECT
      @UNIT_ID,
      TICKETTOTAL,
      CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, DATECREATED, 103) DATECREATED,
      CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, REFUNDDATE, 103) REFUNDDATE,
      DEBITAMOUNT,
      CREDITAMOUNT,
      TERMINALID,
      CASHIER,
      TERMINAL,
      REFUNDMINS,
      MANAGER,
      USERID,
      ID 
   FROM
      @SERVER_NAME.@DATABASE_NAME.dbo.VW_REFUNDS 
   WHERE
      CONVERT(DATE, DATECREATED, 103) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE(), 103);
FETCH NEXT 
   FROM
      DATACURSOR INTO @UNIT_ID,
      @SERVER_NAME,
      @DATABASE_NAME;
END;
CLOSE DATACURSOR;
DEALLOCATE DATACURSOR;
END;
```

Comment: I am trying to access databases in loop which are in different different servers but i am getting error "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_DATA_EXTRACTOR, Line 27
Incorrect syntax near '@DATABASE_NAME'."

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql

Comment: i have already resolved same..